# Replace underscores with dash in Class names for any object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a javascript call (jQuery OK) to change from something like this

```
<div class="demo pass_no def_yes">.. </div>
...
<ul class="me lien_u lis__y"> ... </ul>
```

to

```
<div class="demo pass-no def-yes">.. </div>
...
<ul class="me lien-u lis--y"> ... </ul>
```

by replacing underscores (_) with dash (-)

Object can be any dom object. The classes with underscores are generated from another system, which cannot be modified from my end, while the CSS framework (which again cannot be modified) uses dashes in class names.

Comment: `element.className = element.className.replace(/_/g, '-')` ?

Comment: @FelixKling .. not exactly.. as I need to iterate over all the DOM objects..

Comment: Well, it’s part of the solution 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll` to select all elements that have a class with an underscore and replace those classes with a hyphen.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class*='_']")
  .forEach(el => el.className = el.className.replace(/_/g, "-"))
```

```css
.foo-bar-baz {
  color: green;
}

.foo_bar_baz {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=foo_bar_baz>GREEN</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all elements with [document.querySelectorAll('*')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then use [String.prototype.replace(/_/g, '-')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to update the `className` of each DOM node:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(element => {
  element.className = element.className.replace(/_/g, '-');
  if (element.className.trim()) {
    console.log(element.tagName, '->', element.className);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="demo pass_no def_yes">
  <div class="demo pass_no def_yes"></div>
  <ul class="me lien_u lis__y"></ul>
</div>
<ul class="me lien_u lis__y"></ul>
```

Comment: @ghos-h, no worries!